# How Tableau connect to Postgres via ssh tunels?

Tags: postgresql, ssh-tunnel, tableau-desktop

1. I configureted  ssh tunel via Putty with all settings provided by Devops.
2. During tring create connection with Postgre databases get error **29dcd26f -- errorcode**
3. All date was entred correct
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ClX9.png)

Comment: Please configure it so that errors are reported in English.  Or at least translate it for us, but that is less preferred as sometimes seeing the exact wording is important.

Comment: Does tableau desktop exclusively use the desktop and connect directly to the database, or does it connect to a tableau server and ask the tableau server to connect to the database for it?

Comment: @jjanes About
1st question: translate russinan part of the error Important: The user has not been authenticated (by password)
2. It was used desktop version connect directly to the database

Comment: Can you connect over the same tunnel using something simpler, like `psql`?

Comment: "Invalid username or password" is not an error that PostgreSQL itself would generate.  (it says "password authentication failed").  That string could come from something PostgreSQL uses (like pam or krb) and is just getting passed back, but I think it is more likely it is coming from higher up.  Either putty (the tunnel itself is failing) is doing it, or Tablaue is reading the PostgreSQL error and generating a new wording for it.  Can you ask your dba to look in the db server's log file and report what it is saying about the failure?

Comment: @jjanes I connected success to db via Dbeaver

Comment: @jjanes About second comment asked for log file

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem asked my Devops create access to database via VPN and used new  credianls. It was created success connect Tableau to Postgres.